# gRPC stream maintenance

Tags: go, grpc

Say that I am working with a bi-directional stream and the server could be down or the network could be down. How does one go about maintaining a gRPC stream in code? In other words, can `stream` in `stream, _ := myPbClient.Foo(context.Background())` be broken? If so, what do I need to do to repair it? Just acquire a new one?

---

EDIT

I found the `grpc.CallOption` `grpc.WaitForReady(true)`. From its [readme](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/wait-for-ready.md) description:

> If an RPC is issued but the channel is in TRANSIENT_FAILURE or SHUTDOWN states, the RPC is unable to be transmitted promptly. By default, gRPC implementations SHOULD fail such RPCs immediately. This is known as "fail fast," but usage of the term is historical. RPCs SHOULD NOT fail as a result of the channel being in other states (CONNECTING, READY, or IDLE).

> gRPC implementations MAY provide a per-RPC option to not fail RPCs as a result of the channel being in TRANSIENT_FAILURE state. Instead, the implementation queues the RPCs until the channel is READY. This is known as "wait for ready." The RPCs SHOULD still fail before READY if there are unrelated reasons, such as the channel is SHUTDOWN or the RPC's deadline is reached.

So it sounds like if I set `grpc.WaitForReady(true)`, the stream will not fail unless it's in `SHUTDOWN` state? If this is true, when will the grpc be in a `SHUTDOWN` state?

Comment: Yes, just reconnect. If the server-side dies, have the client loop with a blocking connect and it will reconnect when the server is back up & available.

Comment: How do I know if the stream is broken as opposed to some transient network error?

Comment: See my updated comment.

Comment: I run grpc in k8s and have to be tolerant of containers dying for random reasons (OOM, panics etc.). A stream will fail if one end disappears. The other end should be prepared for that event. You can code for a controlled shutdown - but more severe problems occur out in the wild.